# SBT cannot resolve org.apache.hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, sbt

Sorry I am fairly new to Scala and SBT. Here is my build.sbt file

```
name := "test_stream"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

resolvers in ThisBuild += Resolver.bintrayRepo("streetcontxt", "maven")

mainClass in Compile := Some("basepackage.Main")
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.1",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.693",
  "com.streetcontxt" %% "kcl-akka-stream" % "2.0.3",
  "me.maciejb.snappyflows" %% "snappy-flows" % "0.2.0",
  "org.xerial.snappy" % "snappy-java" % "1.1.7.3",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.10.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1"
)
```

And I get the following error:
`sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;2.10.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;2.10.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}::`

Comment: Try to enable debug level logs in sbt: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Logging.html#Change+the+logging+level+for+a+specific+task%2C+configuration%2C+or+project  - it will print out details why that dependency can not be resolved and links which sbt tried to use in order to download dependency.

Comment: I'd to reinstall scala plugin in IDEA, in order to fix it. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

try removing ~/.sbt and ~/.ivy2  and run again

Comment: after that, I am not able to compile anything... `Error while importing sbt project: List(Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.2.8  (this may take some time)...
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8: not found
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8`

Comment: ~/.sbt home directory for entire sbt. In order to clean ivy cache need to remove `~/.ivy2/cache` instead